# Extend internal link functionality

Tags: link-manager

Let there be 3 sites within same Sitecore instance. When a General Link links pages from site A to Site B or Site C, Sitecore returns the relative path, not the complete url, if using the "Internal Link". Is there a way to the complete url of the page, including the domain, when using Internal Links?

In our case, the use of external links is not a solution. Ty.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the domain when doing cross site internal links in the same sitecore instance. If the configuration is correct sitecore will know to resolve the correct site based on the site definitions and will append the domain to the internal links. Do you have an example where this is not working on your setup?

If you wish to customize your links you would need to implement a custom link provider, you can see an example https://www.altudo.co/resources/blogs/how-to-create-sitecore-custom-urls-diy-guide